# Spring scheduled tasks not firing

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks, spring-scheduled

I'm teaching myself Spring, currently on scheduled tasks, and the following code does not fire the scheduled task.

I believe it has something to do with the way I'm setting up the Spring context but that's only a guess - I'm trying to learn Spring so please excuse the ridiculous while loop.

Application.java:

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext rootContext =
                        new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();

        rootContext.register(RootContextConfiguration.class);
        rootContext.refresh();

        while(rootContext != null) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2500);
            } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }

            System.out.println("Loop\n");
        }

        rootContext.close();
    }
}
```

RootContextConfiguration.java:

```
package hello;

import java.util.concurrent.Executor;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.AdviceMode;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncConfigurer;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfigurer;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler;
import org.springframework.scheduling.config.ScheduledTaskRegistrar;

@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync(
        mode = AdviceMode.PROXY, proxyTargetClass = false,
        order = Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE
)
@ComponentScan(
        basePackages = "hello"
)
public class RootContextConfiguration implements
AsyncConfigurer, SchedulingConfigurer {
    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler()
    {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        scheduler.setPoolSize(20);
        scheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("task-");
        scheduler.setAwaitTerminationSeconds(60);
        scheduler.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        return scheduler;
    }

    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor()
    {
        Executor executor = this.taskScheduler();
        return executor;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar registrar)
    {
        TaskScheduler scheduler = this.taskScheduler();
        registrar.setTaskScheduler(scheduler);
    }
}
```

ScheduledTasks.java:

```
package hello;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;

@EnableScheduling
public class ScheduledTasks {

    private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void reportCurrentTime() {
        System.out.println("The time is now " + dateFormat.format(new Date()));
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-scheduling-tasks</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <start-class>hello.Application</start-class>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin> 
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId> 
                <version>2.3.2</version> 
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Here's what I see in my terminal:

```
12:32:36.533 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
12:32:36.541 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
12:32:36.542 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
12:32:36.657 [main] INFO  o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@7a46a697: startup date [Fri Apr 25 12:32:36 PDT 2014]; root of context hierarchy
12:32:36.663 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Bean factory for org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@7a46a697: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@2038ae61: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,rootContextConfiguration]; root of factory hierarchy
12:32:36.691 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
12:32:36.692 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
12:32:36.725 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
12:32:36.728 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
12:32:36.789 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
12:32:36.790 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
12:32:36.791 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
12:32:36.799 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.i.s.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver - Looking for matching resources in directory tree [/Users/cthielen/src/spring/scheduled-tasks/target/classes/hello]
12:32:36.799 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.i.s.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver - Searching directory [/Users/cthielen/src/spring/scheduled-tasks/target/classes/hello] for files matching pattern [/Users/cthielen/src/spring/scheduled-tasks/target/classes/hello/**/*.class]
12:32:36.803 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.i.s.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver - Resolved location pattern [classpath*:hello/**/*.class] to resources [file [/Users/cthielen/src/spring/scheduled-tasks/target/classes/hello/Application.class], file [/Users/cthielen/src/spring/scheduled-tasks/target/classes/hello/RootContextConfiguration.class], file [/Users/cthielen/src/spring/scheduled-tasks/target/classes/hello/ScheduledTasks.class]]
12:32:36.941 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registered bean definition for imported @Configuration class org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfiguration
12:32:36.944 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registering bean definition for @Bean method org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfiguration.org.springframework.context.annotation.internalScheduledAnnotationProcessor()
12:32:36.945 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registered bean definition for imported @Configuration class org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ProxyAsyncConfiguration
12:32:36.946 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registering bean definition for @Bean method org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ProxyAsyncConfiguration.org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAsyncAnnotationProcessor()
12:32:36.950 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registering bean definition for @Bean method hello.RootContextConfiguration.taskScheduler()
12:32:37.056 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassEnhancer - Successfully enhanced hello.RootContextConfiguration; enhanced class name is: hello.RootContextConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$723fae61
12:32:37.056 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor - Replacing bean definition 'rootContextConfiguration' existing class name 'hello.RootContextConfiguration' with enhanced class name 'hello.RootContextConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$723fae61'
12:32:37.060 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassEnhancer - Successfully enhanced org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfiguration; enhanced class name is: org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4cc1c8d2
12:32:37.061 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor - Replacing bean definition 'org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfiguration' existing class name 'org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfiguration' with enhanced class name 'org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4cc1c8d2'
12:32:37.071 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassEnhancer - Successfully enhanced org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ProxyAsyncConfiguration; enhanced class name is: org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ProxyAsyncConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$18e9d438
12:32:37.072 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor - Replacing bean definition 'org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ProxyAsyncConfiguration' existing class name 'org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ProxyAsyncConfiguration' with enhanced class name 'org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ProxyAsyncConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$18e9d438'
12:32:37.086 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor'
12:32:37.088 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor'
12:32:37.089 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
12:32:37.090 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor'
12:32:37.090 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor'
12:32:37.090 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor'
12:32:37.091 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
12:32:37.091 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor'
12:32:37.091 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor'
12:32:37.092 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor'
12:32:37.096 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
12:32:37.098 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor'
12:32:37.098 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor'
12:32:37.098 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor'
12:32:37.099 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
12:32:37.099 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor'
12:32:37.099 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor'
12:32:37.100 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor'
12:32:37.100 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
12:32:37.100 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor'
12:32:37.102 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalScheduledAnnotationProcessor'
12:32:37.102 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalScheduledAnnotationProcessor'
12:32:37.105 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfiguration'
12:32:37.105 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfiguration'
12:32:37.122 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfiguration' to allow for resolving potential circular references
12:32:37.168 [main] INFO  o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4cc1c8d2] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
12:32:37.168 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfiguration'
12:32:37.253 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalScheduledAnnotationProcessor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
12:32:37.258 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalScheduledAnnotationProcessor'
12:32:37.259 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAsyncAnnotationProcessor'
12:32:37.259 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAsyncAnnotationProcessor'
12:32:37.259 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ProxyAsyncConfiguration'
12:32:37.259 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ProxyAsyncConfiguration'
12:32:37.265 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.annotation.InjectionMetadata - Registered injected element on class [org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ProxyAsyncConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$18e9d438]: AutowiredMethodElement for void org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AbstractAsyncConfiguration.setConfigurers(java.util.Collection)
12:32:37.265 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ProxyAsyncConfiguration' to allow for resolving potential circular references
12:32:37.268 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.annotation.InjectionMetadata - Processing injected method of bean 'org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ProxyAsyncConfiguration': AutowiredMethodElement for void org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AbstractAsyncConfiguration.setConfigurers(java.util.Collection)
12:32:37.273 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'rootContextConfiguration'
12:32:37.273 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'rootContextConfiguration'
12:32:37.275 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'rootContextConfiguration' to allow for resolving potential circular references
12:32:37.278 [main] INFO  o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'rootContextConfiguration' of type [class hello.RootContextConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$723fae61] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
12:32:37.279 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'rootContextConfiguration'
12:32:37.290 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - Autowiring by type from bean name 'org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ProxyAsyncConfiguration' to bean named 'rootContextConfiguration'
12:32:37.291 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'taskScheduler'
12:32:37.291 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'taskScheduler'
12:32:37.291 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'rootContextConfiguration'
12:32:37.308 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'taskScheduler' to allow for resolving potential circular references
12:32:37.336 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'taskScheduler'
12:32:37.338 [main] INFO  o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler - Initializing ExecutorService  'taskScheduler'
12:32:37.342 [main] INFO  o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'taskScheduler' of type [class org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
12:32:37.342 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'taskScheduler'
12:32:37.342 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry'
12:32:37.345 [main] INFO  o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ProxyAsyncConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ProxyAsyncConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$18e9d438] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
12:32:37.345 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ProxyAsyncConfiguration'
12:32:37.385 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAsyncAnnotationProcessor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
12:32:37.413 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAsyncAnnotationProcessor'
12:32:37.435 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Unable to locate MessageSource with name 'messageSource': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DelegatingMessageSource@3c72f59f]
12:32:37.440 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Unable to locate ApplicationEventMulticaster with name 'applicationEventMulticaster': using default [org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster@12d4bf7e]
12:32:37.454 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@2038ae61: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,rootContextConfiguration,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor,org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfiguration,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalScheduledAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ProxyAsyncConfiguration,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAsyncAnnotationProcessor,taskScheduler]; root of factory hierarchy
12:32:37.455 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
12:32:37.455 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor'
12:32:37.455 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor'
12:32:37.456 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor'
12:32:37.459 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'rootContextConfiguration'
12:32:37.460 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor'
12:32:37.461 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor'
12:32:37.461 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfiguration'
12:32:37.461 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalScheduledAnnotationProcessor'
12:32:37.461 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ProxyAsyncConfiguration'
12:32:37.461 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAsyncAnnotationProcessor'
12:32:37.461 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'taskScheduler'
12:32:37.463 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Unable to locate LifecycleProcessor with name 'lifecycleProcessor': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor@2928854b]
12:32:37.463 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
12:32:37.464 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalScheduledAnnotationProcessor'
12:32:37.465 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'rootContextConfiguration'
12:32:37.465 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'taskScheduler'
12:32:37.481 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [systemProperties]
12:32:37.482 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [systemEnvironment]
12:32:37.482 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Could not find key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in any property source. Returning [null]
Loop

Loop

Loop

Loop
```

To be clear, the sleeping for 2.5s and print "Loop" is just there to keep the application running to see if the scheduled tasks fire.

What I'm looking for is the scheduled task which prints the time to fire. It does not.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't have a `ScheduledTasks` bean. Annotate your class with `@Component` (or any of its specializations) or declare a `@Bean` method for it in your `@Configuration` class.

---

`@EnableScheduling` belongs on a `@Configuration` class, not on the class which has the scheduled behavior. You can remove it from `ScheduledTasks`.