# How execute cron Job every day at 5 am in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

I want to execute my cron job every day at 5 am, and this is my scheduled task setting:

`@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 5 * * ?")`.

But this does not work. Does anyone know where is my problem and push any example?

Comment: why doesn't your current cron work - at what times does it execute currently?

Comment: share the code where you have used this Cron. Cron expression is correct. It will be executed at 5 am UTC Time.

Comment: Execute the just first time and after that not.

Comment: does the first execution finish?

Comment: Yes, first execution finished well.

Comment: please share the code.

Comment: Did you also add `@EnableScheduling` to your main class?

Comment: Yes I enabled the `@EnableScheduling` and other cron jobs work well but this executed once and not after that. I can not share the code.

Comment: @SIn san sun If you cannot share the code snippet, we cannot find out why without more clues.

Comment: Note that, this inbuilt scheduler is jvm based and if the java process crashed or so, it won't run. As others asked, please share logs on specific timing and/or add debug logs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring scheduled tasks not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23301622/spring-scheduled-tasks-not-firing)